# GROUP_CONCAT a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, database

So here's the SQL I have

```
SELECT c.name AS 'name',
  COUNT(sc.condition_id) AS 'conditions_count'
FROM reviews r, strain_conditions sc
LEFT JOIN conditions c ON sc.condition_id = c.id
WHERE sc.strain_id = 1 && sc.review_id = r.id && r.moderated = 1
GROUP BY sc.condition_id
ORDER BY conditions_count DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Which returns

```
+---------------+------------------+
| name          | conditions_count |
+---------------+------------------+
| Fiber Myalgia |                2 |
| Anxiety       |                2 |
| ADHD          |                1 |
+---------------+------------------+
```

What I need to do is GROUP_CONCAT the name results so my end result is simply

"Fiber Myalgia, Anxiety, ADHD"

Comment: Do you want them to appear in any specific order or doesn't it matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap it in a subquery. try this,

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(f.name) as `name`
FROM
(
    SELECT c.name AS 'name',
           COUNT(sc.condition_id) AS 'conditions_count'
    FROM reviews r, strain_conditions sc
    LEFT JOIN conditions c ON sc.condition_id = c.id
    WHERE sc.strain_id = 1 && sc.review_id = r.id && r.moderated = 1
    GROUP BY sc.condition_id
    ORDER BY conditions_count DESC
    LIMIT 3
) f
```

Answer (score 3):

You need nested selects because the `LIMIT` should only apply to the subquery.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name
FROM
(
    SELECT c.name AS name
    FROM reviews r, strain_conditions sc
    LEFT JOIN conditions c ON sc.condition_id = c.id
    WHERE sc.strain_id = 1 && sc.review_id = r.id && r.moderated = 1
    GROUP BY sc.condition_id
    ORDER BY conditions_count DESC
    LIMIT 3  
) AS T1
```

If you want them ordered by descending count you should add an `ORDER BY` to the `GROUP_CONCAT`.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY conditions_count DESC) AS name
FROM
(
     -- your query here
) AS T1
```

If you also want the space after the comma, use `SEPARATOR`:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name ORDER BY conditions_count DESC SEPARATOR ', ') AS name
FROM
(
     -- your query here
) AS T1
```

For more details, see the manual page for [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Answer (score 1):

You need to place that in a sub-select:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS name
FROM
(
  SELECT c.name AS 'name',
    COUNT(sc.condition_id) AS 'conditions_count'
  FROM reviews r, strain_conditions sc
  LEFT JOIN conditions c ON sc.condition_id = c.id
  WHERE sc.strain_id = 1 && sc.review_id = r.id && r.moderated = 1
  GROUP BY sc.condition_id
  ORDER BY conditions_count DESC
  LIMIT 3
) x
```